# How do i get text value from listview when it is clicked?

Tags: android, text

I binded one image and 3 textviews in listview. When i secelt the particular row i got image and dispaly it in a separate list but i want to get the remaining 3 textviews text of that selected row and display in another list

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have an image with three options each represented by textViews and when the image is selected you want those options to be entered in a new list? Why not save the textViews in the OnItemSelected() method?  Once the image is picked it can create 3 new textViews linked to the text from those 3 textViews and then you can add those to a list in the same way you did your original list.